# new Date(...).toISOString() in JavaScript gives incorrect result on one day of the year

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I'm building a calendar and I noticed that the date is incorrect on one day of the year.

I wanted to standardize dates to ISO 8601. Let's take `2022-03-27` for example:

```
const foo = new Date(2022, 2, 27).toISOString()
```

This gives `2022-03-27T00:00:00.000Z` as one would expect.

However, the next day, `2022-03-28`:

```
const bar = new Date(2022, 2, 28).toISOString()
```

This gives `2022-03-27T23:00:00.000Z` - 27th March at 23:00.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This does happen in firefox. `new Date(2022, 2, 28).toISOString()` outputs `2022-03-27T23:00:00.000Z` for me (I'm in BST - UTC+1)

Comment: Probably has something to do with the Daylight Savings ("Summer Time") cutover. Well that's a guess.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Oops, my mistake... I'm also in BST, but I just realised I have `privacy.resistFingerprinting` turned on in Firefox, which probably is the cause. I'll edit my question. I'm still curious about why it happens and how to avoid it, though.

Comment: **It's just daylight savings time (British Summer Time) kicking in.** You're creating a date at midnight **local time**. The timezone of the string from `toISOString`, though, is GMT (UTC), not local time. In the UK, [we start British Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/uk/london) at 01:00 on March 27th. So your local time on the 28th is offset an hour from GMT. There are **lots** of questions about this, I'll see if I can find a duplicate...

Comment: Personally when I'm creating Date instances where I don't care about the time-of-day, I use hour 12 (noon) instead of 0, because that *usually*, or at least often, avoids weird stuff like this.

Comment: @Pointy - Just don't do that in New Zealand, Phoenix Island, Tokelau, or Tonga. ;-) Those are GMT+13. https://24timezones.com/time-zone/gmt+13 (There are also places that use GMT+12)

Comment: I couldn't find a clean dupetarget, so I posted a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: That fascinating and depressing Tom Scott video about time and computing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that [British Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london) (Daylight Saving Time, aka DST) is kicking in between your two examples (specifically, it starts at 01:00 on 2022-03-27). `toISOString` always gives you UTC time (GMT) as you can tell from the `Z` at the end of the string, but your local time is an hour ahead of UTC after 01:00 on 2022-03-27 until DST ends at 02:00 on 30 October 2022.

In your first example, you're creating a `Date` with the **local** time of midnight on 2022-03-27, when your local time is (apparently) GMT+00:00 (like mine here in the UK). So `toISOString` gives you back `00:00` because your local time is GMT/UTC (that date/time is an hour before DST kicks in).

But in your second example, you're creating a `Date` in **local** time at midnight on 2022-03-28, when you're on DST. So you're offset from UTC by an hour (UTC is one hour behind you). Midnight 2022-03-28 UK time is 23:00 2022-03-27 UTC.

I don't know what you want to do with this stuff, but if you want to create a `Date` for midnight UTC on 2022-03-28, use `new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 2, 28))`.